# diffculty using bash to pass the contents of `top` into a json file

Tags: json, bash

I want to use a bash script to output the contents of `top` command and then write it to a json file.  But I'm having difficulty writing the slashes/encodings/line breaks into a file with a valid json object

Here's what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

message1=$(top -n 1 -o %CPU)
message2=$(top -n 1 -o %CPU | jq -aRs .)
message3=$(top -n 1 -o %CPU | jq -Rs .)
message4=${message1//\\/\\\\/}

echo "{\"message\":\"${message2}\"}" > file.json
```

But when I look at the `file.json`, it looks soemthing like this:

```
{"message":""\u001b[?1h\u001b=\u001b[?25l\u001b[H\u001b[2J\u001b(B\u001b[mtop - 21:34:53 up 55 days,  5:14,  2 users,  load average: 0.17, 0.09, 0.03\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49m\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49m\u001b[K\nTasks:\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49m\u001b[1m 129 \u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49mtotal,\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49m\u001b[1m   1 \u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49mrunning,\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49m\u001b[1m 128 \u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49msleeping,\u001b(B\u001b[m
```

Each of the other attempts with `message1` to `message4` all result in various json syntax issues.

Can anyone suggest what I should try next?

Comment: use `-b` otherwise top output will contain terminal control codes

Comment: perfect, the final solution was `message2=$(top -b -n 1 -o %CPU | jq -aRs .); echo "{\"message\":${message2}}" > file.json`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all the whistle of `echo` and multiple `jq` invocations:

```sh
top -b -n 1 -o %CPU | jq -aRs '{"message": .}' >file.json
```

Or pass the output of the `top` command as an argument variable.
Using `--arg` to pass arguments to `jq`:

```sh
 jq -an --arg msg "$(top -b -n 1 -o %CPU)" '{"message": $msg}' >file.json
```